# SUMAPRODUCTO condicional - Excel, R o SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, r, excel

tengo una base de datos que sea parece a la siguiente:

```
Fecha   Calif   clientes   Beta
201601    R3       70      3.69%
201601    R4       12     10.97%
201601    R5       11     16.56%
201601    R6        6     31.02%
201601    R7        3     36.90%
201602    R3       73      3.72%
201602    R4       11     12.36%
201602    R5        9     18.98%
  .                        .
  .                        .
  .                        .
202012    R8        4      36.90%        
202012    R10       1      90.00%
```

Las fechas son solo añomes, y están organizadas por mes desde 2016 hasta diciembre de 2020. En las categoría Calif, los niveles van desde R3 a R10. Algunos años, pueden aparecer todas las Calif R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10 y en otras fechas pueden solo aparecer algunas de estas.

Problema: Quiero crear una columna en donde pueda hacer la función SUMAPRODUCTO con los datos de las columnas: clientes y Beta. Pero el largo de esas matrices, debe ser del largo de cada mes de cada año, es decir:

```
Fecha   Calif   clientes   Beta    Sumaprod
201601    R3       70      3.69%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((70,12,11,6,7)(3.69%,10.97%,16.56%,31.02%,36.90%))  
201601    R4       12     10.97%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((70,12,11,6,7)(3.69%,10.97%,16.56%,31.02%,36.90%))
201601    R5       11     16.56%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((70,12,11,6,7)(3.69%,10.97%,16.56%,31.02%,36.90%))
201601    R6        6     31.02%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((70,12,11,6,7)(3.69%,10.97%,16.56%,31.02%,36.90%))
201601    R7        3     36.90%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((70,12,11,6,7)(3.69%,10.97%,16.56%,31.02%,36.90%))
201602    R3       73      3.72%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((73,11,9)(3.72%,12.36%,18.98%))
201602    R4       11     12.36%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((73,11,9)(3.72%,12.36%,18.98%))
201602    R5        9     18.98%   =SUMAPRODUCTO((73,11,9)(3.72%,12.36%,18.98%))
```

En Excel intenté poner `=SI(Fecha, SUMAPRODUCTO, "NA")`, pero al arrastrar esta fórmula las matrices que quiero se me van moviendo y lo que quiero es que para el mismo añomes, siempre me aparezca el mismo valor.

EDICIÓN: También intenté fijar las celdas con $, pero al hacerlo no me funciona porque al cambiar el añomes, no variaría la matriz. El resultado que quiero, dada la fórmula de esa nueva columna sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la fecha 201602, cambia la matriz y por eso no puedo fijarlo en toda la columna. Ahí está fijado pero porque lo hice a mano y en 201602 cambié a mano la matriz.

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer esto? Espero haber sido clara. Cualquier propuesta con otro lenguaje de programación como R o SQL también es bienvenido. Gracias

Comment: Con la ayuda de este operador `$` puedes hacer que tome celdas estáticas.

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero si dejo estáticas las celdas, no me va a variar la matriz cuando cambie el añomes

Comment: Puedes agregar el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: Listo, agregué la imagen

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que Beta esta almacenada como porcentaje (ej. 3.69% = .0369, de lo contrario dividir Beta entre 100) la consulta es:

```
SELECT sum( t2.clientes * t2.Beta )
  FROM tabla t2
  WHERE t2.Fecha = <ParametroFecha>
```

La cual puede ser una consulta escalar:

```
SELECT t.*
     , ( SELECT sum( t2.clientes * t2.Beta )
           FROM tabla t2
           WHERE t2.Fecha = t.Fecha
       )
  FROM tabla t
```

Answer (score 0):

Estabas cerca. Tu SUMAPRODUCTO le faltaba una parte combinada con operador doble unario para seleccionar solo las filas del mismo mes y año:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en E es:

```
=SUMAPRODUCTO(--($A$2:$A$9=A2)*$C$2:$C$9;$D$2:$D$9)
```

El truco está en esta parte: `--($A$2:$A$9=A2)` Esto devolverá una matriz de 1 y 0 dependiendo de si coincide o no con el año y mes de la fila.