# ¿Para evaluar cruce entre rangos de fechas en Excel se usa solo fórmulas o macros VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, excel-2010

Tengo una tabla con rango de fechas de vigencia de clases que debo cruzarlo con grados con sus propios rangos de fechas.

La primera tabla son de las clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda tabla son los rangos de los grados a cruzar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver los rangos de grados a veces aparecen 2 en un mismo intervalo de A (para ese criterio se escoge el primero) o incluso empiezan antes de la fecha de inicio del intervalo B y ese mismo se selecciona al ser el primero en el intervalo y así.

La respuesta sería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si para ese tipo de cruces se utiliza alguna fórmula de excel que compare una fecha entre 2 intervalos de fechas o es necesario una macro. Espero puedan ayudarme a poder encontrar una forma de realizar estos cruces de intervalos. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por qué se recomienda X4 si está fuera del rango de la clase C? La fecha fin de X4 es posterior a la fecha fin de la clase C. Por otro lado. ¿qué has intentado? ¿Qué formulas o macros has probado? ahora mismo tu pregunta es un poco "trabaja gratis para mí :D " Además, es conveniente que añadas cómo lo calcularías a mano para poder formularlo

Comment: Porque no encuentro una fórmula de excel para ello, esas cosas los hago a mano. O si es por macros un método o un ejemplo generalista que pueda ya adaptar a mis necesidades ayudaría. Ya me dieron una guía de una anterior pregunta que pude adaptarlo a mis necesidades y me ayudó. Si no desea darme un tip eres libre de pasar la pregunta y no responder de esa forma.

Comment: Lo primero que pregunté fue *Por qué se recomienda X4 si está fuera del rango de la clase C? La fecha fin de X4 es posterior a la fecha fin de la clase C* pero ha ignorado esa parte y se ha centrado en la siguiente.. Si no desea realizar el más mínimo esfuerzo para solucionar el problema, eres libre de ignorar mi comentario y no responder de esa forma.

Comment: Con Excel 2016 hay una función [`MIN.SI.CONJUNTO`](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599) (aquí `MIN.SI.CONJUNTO(Vigencia_desde;Vigencia_desde;">="&[@inicio];"Vigencia_hasta";"<="&[@fin])`) que devuelve la línea del grado. Pero esta función no existe con Excel 2013 y anteriores :-(

Comment: @AntoineL MIN.SI.CONJUNTO en versiones anteriores de Excel se puede simular con SUMAPRODUCTO y operadores dobles unarios. Un ejemplo similar se puede ver [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438549/sumaproducto-condicional-excel-r-o-sql-mysql)